# Shannon inequalities

Tags: information-theory, entropy

I have some difficulties in showing the relationship between mutual information

$I(X; Y |Z)$ and $I(X; Y)$?

What is larger?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either can be larger, or they can be equal. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interaction_information has some informative examples.